# Why are the Y-axis values of strokes that are exactly at the same Y-axis value different in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

While I was creating a basic outline for part of a graphic using strokes, I noticed that under the Properties panel's "Transform" section, the Y-axis values for 2 strokes I created on the same "y-value" show up and display as completely different "numbers" for their "Y:" value.

Why is this? Or what is it that I am missing?

Please find below screenshots of what I am talking about:

(To illustrate this more clearly, I made one of the strokes brown in color and the other black.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you post a picture of the entire artboard ? It appears as though your lines continue on and are maybe attached to other non straight segments ? Illustrator gives the Y value based upon the entire path's center point. If you want to check that those path ends are aligned select each end point with the Direct Selection Tool ( white arrow) and check that the Y values are the same.

Comment: Looks like you haven't selected the anchor point. Use the Direct Selection tool (A) to select the anchor point you wish to examine.

Comment: There's got to be a reason one object has a height (`H`) and the other doesn't.  As in.. the black is actually more than a single path segment and the brown is only a single path segment -- path direction would possibly account for different Y values.